# PII fields with docx4j

Tags: docx4j

Is there any way to enforce Personally Identifiable Information (PII) functionality with docx4j API such that PII locked fields appear as "****" and not get replaced by their actual key value? Also, is there a way to process a password protected mail merge template?

Comment: These are 2 separate questions, so please split them.  Regarding the PII question, can you explain more fully what you mean?

Comment: @JasonPlutext
In our web application, the PII fields can be locked and the locked fields appear as "****" until they are unlocked using PII password. How are these handled in docx4j API? Can we achieve a functionality wherein PII locked fields, upon mail merge would still appear as "*****" and not be replaced by its actual value?